# React will not console log name of checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have a function that simply grabs all the checkboxes with the same class element and then console logs only the first one. I am trying to simply console log the name of that checkbox that I set, but it does not seem to be working.

It does however console log the style or className when I try it, but not just the name.

**Code:**

```
const handleAddColorCheckbox = (checkbox)=>{
        const checkboxs1 = document.querySelectorAll('.addnote-color')
        console.log(checkboxs1[0].style)
    }

<input type='checkbox' name='addnote-color-white'/>
<span className='addnote-color pointer' name='white' style={{'--addnote-color-selector': '#ffffff'}}/>
```

Comment: Just asking, why would you use querySelectors or basically coding in vanilla js meanwhile "using" react?

Comment: Where do you call `handleAddColorCheckbox`?

Comment: @EDev I am still learning React. I like to learn and pick up new tricks as I go.

Comment: @Konrad I call it on a onClick event on a simple button on the page just for testing right now.

Comment: Works fine for me https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-swanson-foc4ii?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You're missing crucial code from your question which isn't helpful if you want us to help you debug the problem. [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002). @Blazing

Comment: @Konrad style and everything else seems to log fine, but not .name :(

Comment: @Blazing `span` doesn't have a `name` attribute, but it works anyway. Look at the sandbox again

Comment: Your code and question don't appear to be consistent. Based on the code snippet provided, your `handleAddColorCheckbox` is not targeting your `checkbox` element but rather the `span` element.

Answer (score 1):

You can either attach a listener to each checkbox or, similarly to vanilla JS, you can use a form of event delegation* by attaching one listener to a parent component and catching events from its children.

*React uses a synthetic events system whereby all events are attached to the document root rather than individual nodes. So really everything is delegated - you just don't notice it.

Here's a simplified example that has a listener on a parent component that catches events from its children. When it catches one it calls the handler which determines whether the element was a checkbox, and then logs its name.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  function handleClick(e) {
    if (e.target.matches('[type="checkbox"]')) {
      const { name } = e.target;
      console.log(name);
    }
  }

  return (
    <section class="inputs" onClick={handleClick}>
      <input type="checkbox" name="addnote-color-red" />
      <input type="checkbox" name="addnote-color-white" />
      <input type="checkbox" name="addnote-color-blue" />
    </section>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is getting this inline style and the name, here's a solution using querySelectorAll(I'm not sure why you chose to use that though)

```
    console.log(checkboxs1[0].attributes[2].value);
    console.log(checkboxs1[0].attributes[1].value);
```

First line will print the inline style which is the third attribute.
Second line will print the name, which is the second attribute.